# Problems installing astropy

Tags: python, astropy

I'm having trouble installing **astropy** for python.
when I enter 'pip install astropy' in the terminal I get this message:

```
Collecting astropy
Using cached astropy-1.0.4.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/8g/ggchkyrx1xv7jk9df887m1cr0000gq/T/pip-build-63p1fldn/astropy/setup.py", line 49, in <module>
    adjust_compiler(NAME)
  File "/private/var/folders/8g/ggchkyrx1xv7jk9df887m1cr0000gq/T/pip-build-63p1fldn/astropy/.eggs/astropy_helpers-1.0.3-py3.4.egg/astropy_helpers/setup_helpers.py", line 197, in adjust_compiler
    if re.match(broken, version):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 160, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: can't use a bytes pattern on a string-like object

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/private/var/folders/8g/ggchkyrx1xv7jk9df887m1cr0000gq/T/pip-build-63p1fldn/astropy
```

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Are you on OS X?  It seems the `setup.py` of astropy is trying to avoid using the *llvm-gcc* compiler on your system.  There may be a bug in one of astropy's helper methods, but you can try to avoid it going down this code path by explicitly making **clang** your default compiler:

```
$ export CC=clang
$ export CXX=clang++
$ export FFLAGS=-ff2c
```

Then re-run `pip install astropy`

**EDIT:**  Since the above isn't working for you, try a manual installation.

Install Xcode Command Line Tools so as to ensure `clang` is installed on your system:  http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/

```
xcode-select --install
```

Set the environment variable `CC` configuring `clang` as your default compiler

```
export CC=clang
```

Download the astropy tarball

```
curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/astropy/astropy-1.0.4.tar.gz
```

Unzip the astropy tarball

```
tar zxvf astropy-1.0.4.tar.gz
```

Change directory to the`astropy-1.0.4` folder

```
cd astropy-1.0.4
```

Try to manually patch the bug that's causing the install to fail.  First open up `setup_helpers.py` in a text editor

```
vim astropy_helpers/astropy_helpers/setup_helpers.py
```

Modify line 110.
Remove the "**b**".

i.e. Change:

```
(b'i686-apple-darwin[0-9]*-llvm-gcc-4.2', 'clang')
```

To:

```
('i686-apple-darwin[0-9]*-llvm-gcc-4.2', 'clang')
```

Execute the manual installation from the `astropy-1.0.4/` folder:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: This looks like the right idea.  It is indeed a bug, which seems to only occur if you're using an unknown or otherwise broken compiler.  In this case the [`get_compiler_version`](https://github.com/astropy/astropy-helpers/blob/master/astropy_helpers/setup_helpers.py#L202) function returns the string `'unknown'`, when it should be returning a bytes object (or vice versa).  Joe's solution should work here, unless you don't have `clang` either.  I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/astropy/astropy-helpers/issues/182

Comment: By the way, if you don't have a C compiler at all you could work around this bug by setting `export CC=/bin/echo` or something like that, though the package will still fail to install in that case--it needs a C compiler to build (consider also using a scientific python distribution with pre-built binaries for Astropy)

Comment: So any more thoughts on what I can do right now? I kinda need it for work. By the way, I had a different error before, and I saw someone here with a similar error suggest doing this: 'sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2'. After that I got this error.

Comment: Try installing Xcode Command Line tools, then run the pip install again:  http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/  If it doesn't work immediately after installing Xcode Command Line tools, try setting the CC environment variable as shown in my answer.

Comment: Tried it, no difference.

Comment: Updated the answer with an alternate manual installation method.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, still doesn't work, now I get a long error where the bottom line is: 'RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program'.